# Handling dynamic settings of programms

Tags: java, save, settings

I am programming a settings manager for a game.

Essentially I am displaying settings for that game that can only be reached via console and not via ingame menu.

The settings or commands have different values.

For example:

`dota_player_units_auto_attack` has a boolean parameter, 0 or 1

while `dota_health_per_vertical_marker` has an integer parameter (250 default)

**How should i handle/save those settings/commands?**

My first idea was to use a HashMap with settings name as key and bool as a value but this does not work for the integer parts. Should I just define value in Integer and check for 1 and 0 ?

I would love to just use `HashMap` with dynamic values.

cheers.

Comment: You can use a `Map<String, Object>`, but you'll have to keep track of what has which type somehow.

Comment: hmm if i go that route i could create obj setting which has int and bool as attr. default of both is null and i can check which is set. but this feels the same like going integer route... thanks for your answer! it covers my issue of dynamic values. you can write it as an answer if you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use `XML` as store of data.
For temporary data store you cat use something like:

`HashMap<String, TypeAndValuePare> = ...;`

Where `TypeAndValuePare` is:

`class TypeAndValuePare {
     int typeId;
     Object value;
}`

Or just use `HashMap<String, Object>` check the type by `instanceof`.

Comment: interesting. xml is new to me but everyone suggests it to me so i will try to use it. this might be the cleanest solution.

Comment: xml is quite easy to learn, but there is some dangerous places... so don't use java xml methods without tutorial ;)

Answer (score 1):

Java has a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class which is very useful for implementing settings like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the settings in a separate class as follows.

```
public class SettingsManager{

 private boolean dota_player_units_auto_attack;
 private int dota_health_per_vertical_marker;

}
```

and have getters to read the values and setters or constructor parameters to set the values.

Comment: the game has 2500 commands. saving them like this is quite chaotic.i am not quite sure if i should write the commands directly into the program or if i should write it into a file that gets read at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep simple structure for the configuration, my suggestion is that you should not think about `boolean` as some different structure than integer. Every configuration has it own integer value, that application should respond correctly. In you case if variable `dota_player_units_auto_attack` has value 1 then some action is performed if not. Then not.

See that same logic you use for other configuration properties. That is why having consistent structure of such file will benefit in future if you will implement some innovation.

I think that base rule KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid), has its best appliance here.

Going future in your problem you could have a enumeration, with possible option that deliver a default value that app should use when can not gain any other. This will for sure increase your code readability and reliability.

Comment: default values or old valid values will be set (or rather nothing will be changed) if nothing valid has been entered.